# VSCode plugin to show included files for the active page

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins, navigation, include, dreamweaver

I recently changed from Dreamweaver to VSCode and one of the few things I miss about Dreamweaver is the functionality to easily view and navigate to files included in the file being viewed, no matter where the files were located.
This was true of ASP Classic and PHP files where any file included in the page (e.g. #include 'code/file1.asp', require_once('page/file1.php') or script src='js/file1.js') was displayed below the navigation bar in Dreamweaver (now called 'breadcrumbs' in VSCode). Each file name could be viewed and clicked to quickly navigate and view it.

VSCode breadcrumbs feature shows the files in the same directory as the file being viewed, not the same thing.

Does such a plugin exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links)